# PyQt5 Filebrowser Signal-Slot: connecting QTreeView to QColumnview

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, signals-slots, qtreeview

I want to create a little Filebrowser as described here, but by using PyQt5: [Youtube-Video-Description](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92biLZST6Vg)

So far the Layout is working fine. Now I would like to implement the function that the files show up on the left QColumnView. Meaning the files of the clicked folder in the QTreeView can be seen on the right File-QColumnView. I don't get the point of how to create the right signal to set the pathindex for the QFileSystemModel of the QColumnView. Besides, it would be nicer if i could only show one (the name) column of the Folder-QTreeView.
Here is the code for the Browser:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView, QFileSystemModel, QApplication, QColumnView, QDockWidget, QMainWindow, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt

rootpath = QDir.currentPath()

class Browser(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Browser, self).__init__()
        self.createDockWindows()
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
    def createDockWindows(self):
        dock = QDockWidget("Folders", self)
        dock.setAllowedAreas(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)
        #Code to Create FileView Colums and FolderTree
        self.FileView = QtWidgets.QColumnView()
        self.FileView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 10, 291, 281))
        self.FolderTree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.FolderTree.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 221, 281))
        FolderTree = self.FolderTree
        #FolderTree.hidecolumn(1),... ?? to show only name column

        #include FolderTree to a Dock at the left side
        dock.setWidget(FolderTree)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, dock)
        #set the model and rootpath for filling the FolderTree from self.ui
        dirmodel = QFileSystemModel()
        #set filter to show only folders
        dirmodel.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.AllDirs)
        dirmodel.setRootPath(rootpath)
        #filemodel and filter for only files on right side
        filemodel = QFileSystemModel()
        filemodel.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.Files)
        filemodel.setRootPath(rootpath)
        FolderView = self.FolderTree
        FolderView.setModel(dirmodel)
        FolderView.setRootIndex(dirmodel.index(rootpath))
        FileView = self.FileView
        FileView.setModel(filemodel)
        dock = QDockWidget("Files", self)
        dock.setWidget(FileView)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock)

        #important lines for the connection, which does not work    
        self.FolderTree.clicked['QModelIndex'].connect(self.setpathonclick)
    def setpathonclick(self):
        currentpathindex = self.FolderTree.currentIndex()
        self.FileView.setCurrentIndex(currentpathindex)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Browser()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The last 12 lines are the important lines for the onclick connection of FolderTree and FileOverView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the root index on the column-view:

```
    filemodel = QFileSystemModel()
    filemodel.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.Files)
    filemodel.setRootPath(rootpath)
    ...
    FileView = self.FileView
    FileView.setModel(filemodel)
    FileView.setRootIndex(filemodel.index(rootpath))
```

and then do more or less the same thing in the click handler:

```
    ...
    self.FolderTree.clicked.connect(self.setpathonclick)

def setpathonclick(self, index):
    rootpath = self.FolderTree.model().filePath(index)
    filemodel = self.FileView.model()
    filemodel.setRootPath(rootpath)
    self.FileView.setRootIndex(filemodel.index(rootpath))
```